# How to create animation listener for activity transitions

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I'm currently using:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.push_to_background);
```

for my activity transition, and I've read that this method does not support listeners (which I think is not cool) >:(

I need to listen for when my transition animation has ended, but the recommended way to animate activity transitions is with this method. 
What do?

Comment: *I need to listen for when my transition animation has ended* - why?

Comment: -So I can animate a child element. Under condition X, the activity should greet the user with an animation after the activity has shown itself.
Right now, the child animates during the transition, so it blinks into place when the transition ends.

Comment: Yah.  I don't know how to do that.  I've had plausible results by presuming that the transition is complete when the next Activity's onResume is called...

Comment: @LisaAnne I'm afraid not. Apparently this is the wrong approach, but I don't know/remember the right one. 

:( Sorry.